# Hiding combobox border and drop-down just leaving text when mouse leaves

Tags: wpf, templates, styles

I'm very much a noob at wpf, but I have an application to write that involves hiding certain borders / parts of controls when the mouse has left the parent container.

I've managed to do it for textboxes and buttons just simply using storyboard animations on opacity &or borderbrush colour, but a combobox is a different kettle of fish so it seems, and my guess it's not going to be easy!

Just to reitterate, I need to hide all parts of the control that makes it look like a combobox i.e. the border and the dropdown arrow button - leaving the selected text visible.  Preferably with an animation, when the mouse leaves it's parent container.
This xaml shows the trigger for the TextBox:

```
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.MouseEnter">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource showTextbox}"/>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.MouseLeave">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource hideTextbox}"/>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
```

And this xaml is the storyboard for the animation.

```
        <Storyboard x:Key="showTextbox" >
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="textBox1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.BorderBrush).Color" From="White" To="Black" Duration="0:0:0.25" AutoReverse="False" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="hideTextbox" >
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="textBox1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.BorderBrush).Color" From="Black" To="White" Duration="0:0:0.25" AutoReverse="False" />
        </Storyboard>
```

Thanks for any help or pointers on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with comboboxes is that it is actually comprised of different parts including a togglebutton and popup. So to change its style, you need to change the style of its parts.

an example of changing a combobox's style:
http://blog.xamltemplates.net/?p=12

if you use the code from that example, then to do what you want, change 'ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton' Style:

- to remove arrow, remove the path.
- to add animations, add your triggers in 'ControlTemplate.Triggers' section
- to remove border, change BorderThickness to 0